How can I create a local block cache for iscsi initiator on Linux
To avoid network traffic, I would like to set up a local block cache on the iscsi initiator. I tried to do this with bcache but no luck so far. bcache and dm-cache
seem to assume that iscsi storage and cache storage are both located on same system, while I want to put hte cache on the remote client.
